# Write the following in the form $x + 2^{0.5}y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Write the following in the form $x + 2^{0.5}y$:
>
> $\left(5.5 - 3(2)^{0.5}\right)^{0.5}$

I am not sure how to do it, I though about putting under the same denominator and then trying to put it in a quadratic completed square form (if that makes sense) - so that I get one bracket squared which should cancel out the square root.

Unfortunately I can't find how to do it, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You can square it and then solve the equations .

Comment: its not an equation though

Comment: the question is to write that in the form that I said, which requires some manipulation

Comment: I'll explain it better . Treat $x$ and $y$ like variables you want to find . Now square the equation to get $$\frac{11}{2}+5\sqrt{2}=x^2+2y^2+2xy\sqrt{2}$$ Now you want that : $$\frac{11}{2}=x^2+2y^2$$ and also $$2xy=5$$ so now just solve the system of equations .

Comment: Oh ok thanks :D, where does $\frac{11}{2}+5\sqrt{2}=x^2+2y^2+2xy\sqrt{2}$ come from?

Comment: Are you sure the numbers are right because I haven't found any real numbers that work . Please check it .

Comment: the answer is $-1+1.5(2)^{0.5}$, it works and yes numbers are correct

Comment: This is from squaring the following : $$\sqrt{\frac{11}{2}+5\sqrt{2}}=x+y\sqrt{2}$$ Isn't this the question ?

Comment: oh sorry no, it is $\sqrt{\frac{11}{2}-3\sqrt{2}}=x+y\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Still where did you get the equation: $x^2+2y^2+2xy\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Never Mind I got it, thanks soon much!

Comment: @ComplexPhi I think you should provide the answer to close it off..now the correct question has been posted ;)! (+1 waiting ;) )

Comment: The answer is $-1+1.5(2)^{0.5}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good way to start by assuming such a form for your radical and then use it to gain new information of $x$ and $y$ (this is a good strategy in general , instead of the guessing way ) :

$$\sqrt{5.5-3\sqrt{2}}=x+y\sqrt{2}$$

Now square it :
$$5.5-3\sqrt{2}=x^2+2y^2+2xy\sqrt{2}$$

Now with a little wishfull thinking (another good strategy ) you may require that the parts with $\sqrt{2}$ are equal and the parts without it are also equal (to make things simpler ) . So now solve the system of equations :

$$x^2+2y^2=5.5$$  and $$2xy=-3$$

I am sure that now you can solve this (for example by eliminating $y$ from the second and plugging in the first and then solving a quadratic )

Finally you should arrive at the only solution : $(-1,1.5)$ .